# Algorithm for rule set optimization

Tags: classification, optimization, genetic-algorithms

I have hand writed classifiers (there are a lot of them). It's implemented as collection of rule sets `IIF - THEN`.
I want to optimize the % of errors. There some classifiers witch have vey big % of `False Positive` and `False Negative` results.

During my reserch about this problem i've found `RIPPER` alghorytm witch, seems like, was designed to solve this kind of problems. 
Also there are `Multi Naive Bias` alghorythm that can be helpfull.

As far as i understand, usualy in `EA` there is `Global Optimization` step, withc usually/sometimes implemented via `RIPPER`.
So, basicly. i have manually generated `rule-set` witch i have optimize now, with `RIPPER` for example.

Is it true? Can You recomend some literature?

Comment: Why not use a decision tree model such as a random forest?

Answer (score 0):

[RIPPER](https://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/algorithm/congreso/slipper.pdf) (Repeated Incremental Pruning to Produce Error Reduction) is a method to automatically learn rule sets.

It has shown to perform better than other decision tree algorithms (e.g., C4.5). However, it performs work than Random Forest.